# How to duplicate rows with incontinuous dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, rows, repeat

I need to duplicate rows with incontinuous dates to fill all the dates in a dataframe.

Suppose this df:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2022-07-05", "2022-07-07", "2022-07-11", "2022-07-15", "2022-07-18"), letter = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c"))
```

The desired output is this df_new:

```
df_new <- data.frame(date = c("2022-07-05", "2022-07-06",
                          "2022-07-07", "2022-07-08", "2022-07-09", "2022-07-10",
                          "2022-07-11", "2022-07-12", "2022-07-13", "2022-07-14",
                          "2022-07-15"),
                 letter = c("a", "a",
                            "b", "b", "b", "b",
                            "a", "a", "a", "a",
                            "c"))
```

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `complete` from `tidyr` to expand the data based on the `min/max` date incremented by '1 day' and then `fill` the `NA` elements in 'letter' by the previous non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = '1 day')) %>% 
  fill(letter)
```